# How to scan files locally for a specific string?

Tags: malware-detection

I've got a website that's been hacked. We restored it, and everything seems to be fine. But google keeps saying that one of the pages on the site is still serving a malicious link. But they will not specifically say which page. So my question, is there a way to download all site files and do a string search?

I'd like to do this on localhost if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I extensively use this bash function for string search purpose:

```
vgrep()
{
    find . -name .repo -prune -o -name .git -prune -o  -type f -name "*"  -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color -n "$@"
}
```

Add this in your ~/.bashrc then source it:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

It will search a string  recursively in your current directory, then it will print the file and the line of the match.

```
vgrep -i "http://suspicious.com" # -i: case insensitive
```

It accepts grep regex argument with '' instead of "".